# Requested value 'VS2015' was not found. - Azure powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, deployment, visual-studio-2015, azure-deployment-slots

I am trying to get my slot info through azure powershell.

To retrieve the info i used

```
Get-AzureWebsite -Name mywebsite -Slot staging
```

but azure powershell throws the below error:

```
Get-AzureWebsite : Requested value 'VS2015' was not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureWebsite -Name mywebsite -Slot staging
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureWebsite], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.GetAzureWebsiteCommand
```

When i try only with `Get-AzureWebsite -Name mywebsite` it perfectly shows data including slot names as

```
Name       : mywebsite
State      : Running
Host Names : {mywebsite.azurewebsites.net}

Name       : mywebsite(staging)
State      : Running
Host Names : {mywebsite-staging.azurewebsites.net}

Name       : mywebsite(dev)
State      : Running
Host Names : {mywebsite-dev.azurewebsites.net}
```

when i google this error **"Requested value 'VS2015' was not found."** i came across this [link](http://www.brandonmartinez.com/2015/07/14/resolve-a-requested-value-vs2015-was-not-found-get-azurewebsite-error-in-powershell/) and this author suggests that to **remove remote debugger** but no luck still i'm getting the error.

Answer (score 8):

The solution for me was to:

1. switch remote debugging ON
2. select VS2013
3. Save
4. Switch remote debugging OFF again
5. Save

I think it is some kind of bug in Azure.

Comment: Yep, seems this is still an issue. It was breaking VSTS build for me today which was super annoying.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [Azure Powershell bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1743281/build-vnext-azure-website-deploy-error-conflict-website-with-given-name-sitename-already-exists) linked with Remote Debugging which cases error message:

> Get-AzureWebsite : Requested value 'VS2015' was not found.

### Workaround is as follows:

**Prerequisites**: Navigate to [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/), select the Web App (or Web Site) with which you have a problem. Open "Application Settings" panel.

1. Set "Remote debugging" to "On"
2. Set "Remote Visual Studio version" to "2013"
3. Set "Remote debugging" to "Off"
4. Save configuration

PS. There is a similar answer here, but not precise enough.

PS2. If there's still the same problem try restoring original value ("VS2015") and repeat the steps with "Saving configuration" between steps 3 and 4.